# A struct inherits itself

Tags: c++, templates

I got a piece of code from my friend. But I am really confused, how can a struct inherit from itself? Does the inheritance make much sense?

```
template<class TYPELIST>
struct Field : public Field<typename TYPELIST::Tail> {
  typedef TYPELIST TypeListType;
  typename TypeListType::Head item_;
};

template<>
struct Field<TypeListEnd> {
};
```

I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Lets make it clear, a struct can never inherit itself as it would be recursive _ad infinitum_. But that's just not whats happening in your code.

Comment: @jweyrich this isn't CRTP; that would be `struct Field: SomeTemplate<Field>`.  This is just C++03 typelist template metaprogramming.

Comment: @ecatmur: true! Just removed my faulty comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Field` doesn't inherit from itself; rather, `template<typename TYPELIST> Field` inherits from `Field<typename TYPELIST::Tail>`.  It's fine as long as the two lists of template arguments are distinct.

Typelists were an archaic method of allowing templates to (in effect) take a variable number of type arguments, before [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template#section_1) were added to the language.  They implemented a simple singly linked list structure, equivalent to LISP cons cells, where `Head` was the "payload" type and `Tail` the remainder of the list, which would either be a typelist or a `TypeListEnd` type, equivalent to LISP `nil`.

Suppose we have

```
typename TypeList<int, TypeList<char, TypeList<float, TypeListEnd> > > MyTypeList;
```

Here I'm assuming that `TypeList` is a template defining `Head` and `Tail` typedef members corresponding to its first and second template parameters respectively:

```
template<typename Head, Tail> struct TypeList { typedef Head Head; typedef Tail Tail; };
```

Note that I'm having to space-separate the closing angle brackets, as this might have to be compiled on a C++03 compiler, where `>>` is always even in template context interpreted as the right-shift operator.

Then your `Field` metafunction, when invoked on `MyTypeList`, will expand into

```
Field<MyTypeList>;

Field<typename TypeList<int, TypeList<char, TypeList<float, TypeListEnd> > > >;

struct Field<...>: TypeList<int, TypeList<char, TypeList<float, TypeListEnd> > >::Tail {
    TypeList<int, TypeList<char, TypeList<float, TypeListEnd> > >::Head item;
};

struct Field<...>: TypeList<char, TypeList<float, TypeListEnd> > {
    int item;
};

...

struct Field<...>: struct Field<...>: struct Field<...>: struct Field<TypeListEnd> {
} {
    float item;
} {
    char item;
} {
    int item;
};
```

This provides you with a `struct` containing by public inheritance all of the types in your typelist.  Of course, doing anything useful with such a `struct` is another matter and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a class template `template <typename X> class SomeTemplate`, then class types `SomeTemplate<A>` and `SomeTemplate<B>` are two completely different, unrelated class types (assuming `A` and `B` are different). Since they are two completely different types, there's nothing wrong with one of them inheriting from the other. `SomeTemplate<A>` can inherit from `SomeTemplate<B>`, which in turn can inherit from `SomeTemplate<C>` and so on, as long as it doesn't become self-referential at some point.

In other words, in your example `struct` does not inherit from itself, as you seem to believe. There's no `struct` in your example at all. Instead your example has several *templates* for  `struct`s. These templates become `struct`s when and only when they are *specialized*, i.e. when all template arguments are replaced with actual types. Because of inheritance, that specialization can turn out either legal or illegal depending on the additional details (which you did not provide).